# ClassNotFoundException while running already-built jar

Tags: java

I added the jar for com.drew.* which is :-

```
metadata-extractor-2.4.0-beta-1.jar
```

I am also able to build my application in Eclipse without any error.
But when I run my application's jar (that includes all the required jars including the above one), I get the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: how did you build the jar? Im wondering if the jar that you build can access your dependancy

Comment: built the jar using export->jar in eclipse.

Comment: nice, I havnt had any dependency issues while using eclipse to generate a jar. How did you add the jar as a dependency? It seems that for whatever reason, this dependency is not on the class path of the built jar.

Comment: Did you try `export->Runnable JAR file` (select the appropriate run configuration) instead of `export->JAR file`?

Comment: @Xeon I always used export->jar and it always worked fine earlier . But this time as you said there might be a dependency version mismatch...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Open executable jar (using `7z`/`WinRAR`, etc.) and look if there is your `metadata-extractor` jar included - also open your Manifest and see if this jar is in the classpath.

In case everything above is fine I think there is probably jar dependency version mismatch.

Do you exporting your executable jar using Eclipse File->Export->Runnable JAR file? It should work just as in the Eclipse

Comment: the classpath is present in the .classpath file inside my application's jar. Classpath isn't a problem. Probably jar dependency version mismatch is the case..

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the classpath in MANIFEST.MF file. You can view this file using any extractor tool. If dependent jar is in folder than provide the folder name in classpath
Entry should look like

```
  Class-Path: folder/jarfilename
```

This will help you further http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like with eclipse when building a jar you [have to choose which resources you would like to be included](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm). Maybe you did not select that jar?